# Need help about the tick format when using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

```
plt.yticks([0,1.25*1e8,2.50*1e8])
```

I want `0` `1.25*1e8` `2.50*1e8`
But I get `0` `1.25` `2.50` with `1e8` on the top.

Answer (score 0):

The scale factor is part of the standard `ScalarFormatter`. If you don't want it use a different formatter, e.g. [`FormatStrFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplots()
plt.yticks([0,1.25*1e8,2.50*1e8])
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%g'))
```

[image]

If you want `2.5e8` instead of `2.5e+08` you'll need to change the formatted string representation using a [`FuncFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter):

```
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x,_: f'{x:g}'.replace('+0','')))
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!  VERY IMPRESSIVE SOLUTION

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer solved your question you should consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), this helps others to quickly find a solution to similar issues. Thanks.